# How to add SQL compact database file to VS 2013 solution

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I have a project that uses SQL Compact DB 3.5. I used to work with VS 2010, and everything was going well, I then installed VS 2012, and opened the project with Visual Studio 2012, it asked me to update the database to 4.0, and I did and it worked. Now I have VS 2013, I installed the SQL Server Compact toolbox, and I managed to connect to the database file during design time, but during runtime, I don't know how to do so,
before I was using this connection string: "Data Source=my_db.sdf;Password=password"
I deleted the converted 4.0 database file, I only have the 3.5 file, and no more VS 2012,
if I add the database file to the solution, it tells me I am using an old version and I need to update it.

The question is: What connection string do I use to connect to the database during runtime which I am successfully viewing in SQL Server Compact Toolbox

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Reference to SqlCe 4.0 and added a reference to SqlCe 3.5 and it worked, thanks anyways, I hope this answer helps anyone